# gcc-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf used to install on disco, missing on impish

Tags: upgrade, gcc, cross-compilation

I have a Dockerfile to build a cross compiling environment for Rust. In the past I have only support musl builds for static executables. When I upgraded from disco to impish I am missing the important package `gcc-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf`.

```
# apt-get install gcc-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

Where can I find a history of package renames to understand the history of this package? It looks like `multilib` packages no longer declare a specific architecture.

Is `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` an equivalent package?

Comment: Which compiler do you use? What is the name of its executable - `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` or different?